# How to fix 504 ERROR with route 53, cloudfront distribution and elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I'm not able to get my nodejs api working using elastic beanstalk, cloudfront distribution and route 53.  I need my api to be running behind an SSL, this is why I'm using cloudfront distribution.  I have the following setup.

When I visit my api `https://api.mydomain.com` I get a 504 with the error message below.

The actual url my api is running on (successfully, using nodejs elastic with beanstalk) is `http://dummy-env.n1eijsdai.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`.  I just want to mask that url as `api.mydomain.com` together with an SSL.

Is there something I've got wrong/ can you suggest anything to try?

Looking through the configuration for cloudfront this looks strange, the picture shows the setting prefixed with S3 but this api is not on an S3 (at least directly) it is hosted by elastic beanstalk.

[image: cloudfront setting that mentions S3 in the value, it's in beanstalk (not S3)]

Thanks,

**Error message**

```
504 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection. 
If you received this error while trying to use an app or access a website, please contact the provider or website owner for assistance.
```

**Route 53**

- name = api.mydomain.com
- Type = (A) Alias target = wqsdn31817

**CloudFront Distributions**

- domain name = wqsdn31817
- origin = dummy-env.n1eijsdai.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com (if I visit this url I see my api running)
- SSL certificate = api.mydomain.com
- status = deployed
- Origin Settings/ Origin Domain Name = http://dummy-env.n1eijsdai.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
- Origin Settings/ Origin Protocol Policy = HTTPS Only

**Elastic Beanstalk**

- Nodejs api (using express)
- In beanstalk Environment ID: e-1nasn4, URL: dummy-env.n1eijsdai.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com

Comment: I am facing a similar problem, but with WordPress in Lightsail. Some requests are succeeding, while others are failiting (error 504). Basically I am using cloudfront to serve main website from s3, while /blog* from lightsail instance. It was working at first, but suddenly the issue popped up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudFront serves 504 only if it couldn't either establish TCP connection or the HTTP first byte response took more then what was configured in Origin read/response timeout.

Does your application work directly with beanstalk link or do you have any security group restriction based on IP  ?

Comment: When I browse the url that beanstalk provides after deploying it my nodejs api is running on http

Comment: Origin Settings/ Origin Protocol Policy = HTTPS Only, you set this cloudfront, does beanstalk work directly on https as well from browser/public ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I found that the security group in load balancer was not  configured.

So I went to. EC2 -> Load Balancers -> select your loadbalancer

Go to Security and add security wizard that was created for EC2 instance.

And you are done.

Comment: This answer solved it. I had an understanding that CloudFront would do API calls to the Load balancer and I did not configure the security group.

Adding the security group solved it. Thanks.